# Visual Studio VB Project config transforms not displaying

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, app-config, transformation

Want to use the app.config transforms and make it obvious in a VB project.

The transform app.config files are created in the VB project. The transforms do get made. However I'm unable to have App.Debug.config and App.Release.config display in the solution explorer.

I've tried 'add existing' to the App.Debug.config, and it will not show in the VB project.

I've also tried editing the vb project, change the case 'app.config' to 'App.config' and it made no difference in the display:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="App.config" />
    <Content Include="App.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="App.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

How can I get a vb project to display the .configs in a similar manner as c# project?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well! It turn out in the solution explorer if one clicks 'show all files' the app.Debug.config and app.Release.config will appear in the VB project.

Comment: Still don't get WHY you have to select 'show all files' to see the transformed configs. In my C# solutions I don't have to select that option.